# iOS UIView no displayed again after setting isHidden to true

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

We have  the following layout in our ViewController

[image]

As you see, it is a UIView containing a TableView, and over the tableview, a custom view that displays a message if there is nothing to display, also when the tableview is empty.

This controller reacts to the content of a local database, by using an event system. The idea is that, if the user does the gesture to refresh the tableview, the local database is deleted, and the controller receives an empty array of items, and the nothing found view should be displayed. After new info is downloaded, and the database is filled with it, the controller receives again an event with the items for the list, (or maybe again the list is empty, etc).

When debugging the view hierarchy, we can see that when starting the ViewController, the custom view "NothingFound" is there in its place. Then, we hide the NothingFound view, while downloading new contents from the server, with isHidden=true.

If it results that the server responded with an empty list, then we want the NothingFound view to be displayed again, and we set isHidden=false.

But it does not work, the view is not displayed again. Examining the view hierarchy, we can see in the navigator that the view disappeared from the hierarchy (we were expecting the view to be there, but in invisible status, but maybe we are wrong).

Maybe we are missing something, but is isHidden = false not supposed to make the view visible again? Or is there another technique to do this?

Thanks in advance

PS: Things we already tried: we already make sure that we are hiding and showing again the view on the main thread, but this does not solves the problem.

We tried to call layoutIfNeeded() after modifying the property isHidden of the view, without result.

Comment: Difficult to answer just by seeing view hierarchy. Please make sure view is in correct state, after fetching operation fails.

Comment: Just place `prints` where new values are set to `isHidden`, that's it and add your code, please.

Comment: @r-Campos can you plz hide your table view and respond that what happened? after fetch data or empty data in all state.

Comment: From which thread do you set `isHidden`?  Have you tried setting `alpha` to 0 or 1 instead?

Comment: Instead of huffing the view, why don’t you display a unique specific cell with the contents of nothing view : in this case you just have to refresh tableView, if no data one row with cell equal nothing cell also normal cells. Anyway your problem may be due to missing or invalid layout constraints.